# Audit for specific Azure DNS in a specific region (Azure Policy)

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I'd like to have an Azure Policy that audits for specific Azure DNS's in the targeted Region. Both should be available in an array so the policy can be scoped multiple times.

So far I've got this, which does not work since it puts the state in compliance by having the right DNS set, but completely ignores the region specified in the array. My goal is to have the policy compliance check for both.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "value": "[if(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')), bool('false'), equals(length(intersection(parameters('dnsSettings'), field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers'))), length(parameters('dnsSettings'))))]",
              "equals": false
            },
            {
              "value": "[if(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')), bool('false'), equals(length(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')),length(parameters('dnsSettings'))))]",
              "equals": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "location",
                "in": "[parameters('location')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "dnsSettings": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "dnsSettings",
        "description": "Audit for specific DNS settings."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Location",
        "description": "Choose specific location",
        "strongType": "location"
      }
    },
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effects",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the Policy."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use auditIfNotExists with few logic operations so that this will allow only after the success code, below sample is to understand about .

```
{
    "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
        "details": {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "existenceCondition": {
                "allOf": [{
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                        "equals": "IaaSAntimalware"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the way we can specify the dns, Sample for adding dns:

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "name": "Deny changing VNet DNS settings from pre-defined value",
    "description": "This Policy will prevent users from changing DNS settings on a VNet",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
                },
                {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "value": "[if(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')), bool('false'), equals(length(intersection(parameters('dnsSettings'), field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers'))), length(parameters('dnsSettings'))))]",
                            "equals": false
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "[if(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')), bool('false'), equals(length(field('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dhcpOptions.dnsServers')),length(parameters('dnsSettings'))))]",
                            "equals": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "auditIfNotExists"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dnsSettings": {
            "type": "array",
            "metadata": {
                "displayname": "Enforced DNS Settings",
                "description": "Users will be unable to change the DNS settings on a VNet from the values defined in this array."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check [AzurePolicy.json](https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/master/Policies/Network/allow-azurefirewallpolicy-user-defined-standard-ports-fqdns-within-application-rules/azurepolicy.json) and [AzurePolicy.rules.json](https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/master/Policies/Network/allow-azurefirewallpolicy-user-defined-standard-ports-fqdns-within-application-rules/azurepolicy.rules.json) to understand about allowing standard dns within application rules. Include location settings in it.